# Laravel Eloquent comparing strings

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying to compare the strings of what is input by the user and what is stored in the database. I am checking for the email and password, and if the correct email an password are provided, then the user is redirected to the respective pages based on the role_type. I have three role types: administrator, user and staff. I am using an if statement to check for the role_types. However, the controller does not redirect me to the intended page. Any ideas why?

Here is a snippet of my code:

**Routes.php**

```
//user login
Route::get('/login', [ 'as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'mainController@login']);
Route::post('/logs_in', 'mainController@logs_in');
//user logout
Route::get('/logout', 'mainController@logout');


//dashoards
Route::get('/admin', [ 'as' => 'admin', 'uses' => 'mainController@admin']);
Route::get('/staff', [ 'as' => 'staff', 'uses' => 'staffController@staff']);
Route::get('/user', [ 'as' => 'user', 'uses' => 'userController@user']);
```

**mainController.php**

```
//user login
    public function login(){
        return view('login');
    }

    public function logs_in(Request $request){
        $email = $request->input('email');
        $password = $request->input('password');

        $hashedPassword = User::where('email', $email)->first();


        $role_type = User::select('role_type')->where('email', $email)-
                     >get()->first();
       // echo $role_type;
            if(Hash::check($password, $hashedPassword->password)){ 
                if($role_type == "Administrator"){ 
                    // $request->session()->put('success');
                    return redirect()->route('admin');
                } else if ($role_type == "Staff") {
                    // $request->session()->put('success');
                    return redirect()->route('staff');
                } else if ($role_type == "User") {
                    // $request->session()->put('success');
                    return redirect()->route('user');
                };
            } else {
                return redirect()->route('login')->with('login_error', 
                'Invalid credentials entered');
            };
    }


    //user logout
    public function logout() {
        Auth::logout();
        return redirect()->route('login')->with('info', 'User logged out 
        successfully');

    }
```

The controller is retrieving info correctly from the views. The problem lies in the redirection of the routes from /logs_in to the respective user pages.

Comment: Please edit your title to match your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be completely honest, I would have done this via a middleware rather than in the controller however, I Believe this is to do with your routes. Please see below for how I'd approach it:

```
Route::get('/admin', 'mainController@admin')->name('admin');
Route::get('/staff', 'staffController@staff')->name('staff');
Route::get('/user', 'userController@user')->name('user');
```

I can only assume each named route is returning a view therefore you should be okay with the above method.

**Further Example**

So just knocked this up for you to look at:

General AdminController:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        $name = '';
        if($name == 'Option')
        {
            return redirect()->route('admin');
        } else {
            return redirect()->route('user');
        }
    }

    public function admin()
    {
        echo 'Admin Page';
    }

    public function user()
    {
        echo 'User Page';
    }

}
```

Routes:

```
Route::get('/', 'AdminController@index');
Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@admin')->name('admin');
Route::get('/user', 'AdminController@user')->name('user');
```

As you can see, my version is hardcoded just to give you a demo.. However, you'll still need to integrate a userRole check middleware to prevent users from being able to access the other pages that they shouldn't be able to access.

Comment: Yes each method is returning a view but the controller is not redirecting to the respective dashboards. I can't understand why that is the case

Comment: @jptl431 I have shown you with the Routes above what you need to do. I have literally just tested this myself :)